# Cannot implement jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my main code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='C:\Projects\summer\css\style.css'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='C:\Projects\summer\js\script.js'></script>
        <script src="C:/Projects/summer/js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="paragraph">Using jQuery</p>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        alert( "welcome" );
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The inline script for the onscreen alert works, however, the following code is not working.

```
$(function () {
    $('#paragraph').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

This is my first time trying to use jQuery (compressed version 1.10.1 from jQuery) on a website and after trying/researching for a couple of days now, I cannot get this to work. (I have also tried wrapping the code in the `$(document).ready(function(){});`)

Comment: Why are some paths using C:/ and others are using C:\?

Comment: Doesn't really matter; they're both wrong!

Comment: what do you have in `script.js`?

Comment: @KevinB: `C:\` is. That backslash needs to be escaped.

Comment: jquery is called after your script

Comment: the paths should be prepended by the file:// protocol

Answer (score 2):

The links you are using for your subresources (e.g, `src='C:\...'`) are incorrect. This path syntax is not used in HTML.

Assuming your HTML file is in `C:\Projects\summer`, you can refer to the subresources with the relative paths:

```
css/style.css
js/script.js
js/jquery.js
```

You will probably also want to load jQuery before your own script, especially if it references jQuery methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you're mixing UNIX-like paths and Windows paths. You really shouldn't using absolute paths anyway. Assuming this file itself is inside the `summer` directory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src='js/script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="paragraph">Using jQuery</p>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        alert( "welcome" );
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. It seems to be working now and thank you for correcting my paths!